# Harassment within a Mathematics department in the USA

Tags: harassment

This is a documentation of some of the documentable behavior of the current Chair of a certain Mathematics department in the US over the last two years:

(i) Him giving me a very small problem, asking me in a cordial way to think about it once I leave his office, and when I come back to tell him I figured it out, him getting suddenly very agitated and snapping, saying in a weird and threatening way, "OK, you win".

(ii) I went to a dinner with a colloquium speaker, having missed his talk due to teaching commitments, and explained that to acting chair at the dinner, and he replied saying, "Oh, that's why we can't throw you out now?"

(iii) Him being the head of the department, and me repeatedly reporting dozens of instances of very seriously insulting and racially motivated comments within the department (Possibly I kept bothering him a bit much about this seeing initially that he was not willing to do anything), and him saying at one point "This is not kindergarten and we are not kindergarten teachers, please sort your own issues".

(iv) One semester I thought I should inform him that I was taking some music lessons, since he was my advisor then. One thing led to another, and he very weirdly and aggressively said; "Can you play the Tchaikovsky Concerto fully if you don't know how to read music?"

(v) Telling a visiting Chinese female PhD student from a prestigious university, in a very weird way , "Good luck in competing for jobs soon, with my own student!", when this PhD student felt very weird and mentioned this incident to others.

(vi) Gratuitously threatening me with expulsion, as the Chair of the department, after I mentioned the need to change advisors after some appalling behavior from the person I was working with for the last one year, (and whose behavior merits another post). Completely dismissing the fact that I have enough work to potentially defend a thesis right now. 
This probably is due to the fact that I once confronted him politely about his past behavior, his harassing statements in the past, and also his being extremely difficult to work with and intransigence in letting me find problems to work on when he was my advisor.

I'm Indian. What are the correct steps to take in this situation, in order to ensure he cannot keep threatening me with expulsion? It's tiring to seek advice this way, and in order to document the behavior of the person I was working with , it would involve more writing. I'm working with a well known mathematician in an adjacent university; and he seems optimistic with the progress; but the Chair says even if my new advisor is happy, my funding will get cut, because he won't accept all the previous work I did.

Comment: It would be good to understand what your objective here is. We can't tell you what the "correct" steps are, if we don't understand what the goal is. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: The only single "threat of expulsion" i can find in your post would be the dinner comment. Is there more somewhere else?

Comment: The last point; he is constantly threatening me with expulsion from the program; I'm working with a fairly well known Mathematician in an adjacent university who seems happy with how things are going. The chair however says he can expel me even if this mathematician thinks things are working well. and that he won't allow me to fall back on the past work.

Comment: @laputalanglang if the last point is the most importnat one, I would say dump the rest of the post and instead expand the last point with actual examples, as it stands it's just very generic summary.

Comment: @laputalanglang You might find more useful assistance over on [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I wouldn't care to bring all of this up, unless for the constant threats of expulsion, in a situation where I have enough to defend a thesis.

Comment: Related discussion on meta: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/when-it-comes-to-questions-which-make-public-accusations-against-people-is-ther

Comment: @laputalanglang The answer they have posted is bad and is probably going to be removed. The meta post however has valid points, we're not a fan of putting anyone's information out on the internet without everyone's explicit permission. It's currently up for review

Comment: @laputalanglang don't post names over there either.

Comment: ..or the quality of your question/rant. Please take a [tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help section](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how to write good and answerable questions..

Comment: indeed in a way it does perhaps!

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/145093/harassment-within-a-mathematics-department-in-the-usa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I would try to have a long conversation with this person to say you know what.

> When you behave this way you are really making me feel bad. As you are in a higher position that makes this a workplace issue. When you make other people feel like they are less worth and that they are replaceable. That's not okay. It is important that we respect each other. Because if you don't respect me and treat me like I'm a special person why should anyone treat you with respect. Why should anyone be kind to you? Why should I make you feel special. You are not the only important person and to be honest this isn't something that I should have to say because this is the kind of things that we learn in kindergarten. The be nice to each other.

And as a final stinger you could say (But shouldn't because that will make things worse):

> Maybe you need to go back to kindergarten, not me

Honestly, hearing this makes me absolutely upset. No one should be forced to feel this way in a workplace. Life is hard enough as it is.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say? "treat me like I'm a special person"?

Comment: I´m saying that you should say that to him. Well he doesn´t treat you like you are special when he treatens to expulse you.

Comment: Why would he have to treat me special? He can just treat me like a normal human being.

Comment: My argument is that we should all treat each other like we are special. Treating someone like they are special can also simply be that . Treating someone like they are human. That ´s enough. Also really mean it. don´t lie and give empty flattery because you wouldn´t do that to someone who is special but rather find the parts that make that person special and say what you really think. I can already tell that you are a smart person who works tremendously hard so I might say to you you know what. I look up to you. I´m not saying that this person needs to be so kind

Comment: *but atleast be kind enough to not make you feel like you are not worthless

Comment: Well thank you for saying that, if you are sincere.

Comment: I am. we are getting off topic, the point is that it might be best to try to grab the bull by it´s horn and talk too him about it. And if it doesn´t get better maybe they don´t deserve you. I´m certain that another institution would love to have you :)  Come to Sweden :)